# `npm run build` works, but `tsc` raises compilation errors?

Tags: next.js, tsc

I'm working in a project using next.js and my team barely ever uses `tsc` directly. I see a lot of compilation errors but the project still is built and runs "ok".

I'm more of a fan of using the compiler (that's the whole purpose of using typescript), but it raises tons of compilation errors.

Now I'm wondering what kind of modified `tsc` compiler options does `next build` uses in order to ignore all those compilation errors, and how do I make `next build` be as forgiving as `tsc`

Comment: Did you mean "make `tsc` be as forgiving as `next build`"? Seems a little contradictory to me.

Comment: Both ways work. if `next build` is as forgiving/strict as `tsc` or viceversa

Comment: Well, I guess you could just `tsc` and pipe the output to `/dev/null`...

Comment: Is the TypeScript version you have installed globally on your local machine the same as the version installed in the Next.js app? Make sure both versions are aligned.